# __try not catching exception on HeapFree

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, try-catch, seh

I'm trying to catch a `HeapFree` exception..

On MSDN it says `HeapFree` has undefined behavior when trying to free an already freed pointer.
Well, I tried that on VS2010, and it "throwed" a breakpoint (windows has triggered a breakpoint), then an exception (a heap has been corrupted)

Im trying to catch that with _*try/*_except but it's not being triggered:

```
__try{      
  HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pMem);
}

__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER){
   DWORD exception = GetExceptionCode();
}
```

How can I catch this exception? normal try/catch also doesn't work. I don't know what's going on; I'm more interested in the explanation than in the solution itself.

Comment: you're saying `try{heapfree(blahblah)}` `catch(heapfreeexception e){//do stuff}` doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know much about practical use of SEH, so I can't answer your question.  However:  **Do not do this.**  If a heap is corrupted, your program is broken.  It is in an unrecoverable state.  The only safe thing to do here is to let the program exit.  Don't try to catch the exception.  Instead, fix the bug in the program that is causing the exception in the first place (most C++ programs should not have to handle SEH exceptions).

Comment: @reagan I tryed with catch(...), no it also doesnt work

Comment: @James I would tend to agree with james here, some exceptions are better understood and fixed than caught

Comment: @James Im just trying it, its not a design decision...Actually Im writting an wrapper to win32 heap functions, really simple, so I settled the exception flag at heap creation and was testing what one could do with the wrapper...The thing is, deallocating an already deallocated pointer seems a common error, Id like to throw an exception when this happens, and was testing what happens when this happens

Comment: "deallocating an already deallocated pointer seems a common error, Id like to throw an exception when this happens" But this is not an exceptional code path, this is a *broken* code path. You should log things and crash hard.

Comment: Review HeapSetInformation, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption class.  This appears to be turned on on my Win7 machine, there is no documented way to turn it off.

Comment: @GManNickG exactly! "you should log things and crash hard", how will I log things if I cant detect the crash??

Comment: @Hans Passant, very informative, specially the last community addition, answers "why"

Comment: Hi @Icebone1000 I wanted to ask whether you managed to resolve this issue. Currently I am having the same problem - I want to catch *all* un-handled exceptions of my process, but these Heap errors destroy the process before I have time to process them...

Comment: @PazO nope..sorry